# JSON - parse multiple level

Tags: json, asp-classic

I am new to JSON and trying to parse multiple levels, but got stuck. I am using the include file called "json2.asp" (link below), which is based on json2.js.

https://github.com/nagaozen/asp-xtreme-evolution/blob/master/lib/axe/classes/Parsers/json2.asp

So, I got to this so far with the code below.

```
Set jsonObj = JSON.parse("{}")
jsonObj.set "Subject", "Testing Event Creation" 
jsonObj.set "Start", "2016-08-30T15:00:00-07:00" 
jsonObj.set "StartTimeZone", "Pacific Standard Time" 
jsonObj.set "End", "2016-08-30T17:00:00-07:00" 
jsonObj.set "StartTimeZone", "Pacific Standard Time"
jsonObj.set "Attendees", array(JSON.parse("{""EmailAddress"": {""Address"":""user1@domain.com"", ""Name"": ""User""},""Type"":""Required""}" ))
```

And the code above produces this output below:

```
{
  "Subject": "Testing ERP Event 2",
  "Start": "2016-08-30T15:00:00-07:00",
  "StartTimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time",
  "End": "2016-08-30T17:00:00-07:00",
  "Attendees": [
    {
      "EmailAddress": {
        "Address": "user1@domain.com",
        "Name": "User"
      },
      "Type": "Required"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, I am stuck on adding additional email addresses under "Attendees" like the example below:

```
{
  "Subject": "Testing ERP Event 2",
  "Start": "2016-08-30T15:00:00-07:00",
  "StartTimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time",
  "End": "2016-08-30T17:00:00-07:00",
  "Attendees": [
    {
      "EmailAddress": {
        "Address": "user1@domain.com",
        "Name": "User1"
      },
      "Type": "Required"      
    },
    {
      "EmailAddress": {
        "Address": "user2@domain.com",
        "Name": "User2"
      },
      "Type": "Optional"      
    },
    {
      "EmailAddress": {
        "Address": "user3@domain.com",
        "Name": "User3"
      },
      "Type": "Required"      
    }
  ]
}
```

I know that I am not doing this correctly.  Please show me an efficient way to perform multiple levels using the json2.asp.  I tried to set "Attendees" as a separate object so I can add email addresses, but no success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I added "json" as the language already.  What language tag do you mean? Please advise.

Comment: Added it.  I am using classing ASP.  Thanks

Comment: Did you try without the `JSON.parse` in `jsonObj.set "Attendees", array(JSON.parse.....`

Comment: I did but no luck.  However, I found a work around which produces the same result.  Thanks for responding.